# How to duplicate div class color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make it comments counter div. If comments as 0 div class is red or more than 0 div class is blue, but javascript duplicating same colors.

```
$(function () {
    if(parseInt($(".notification-counter").text()) > 0) {
        //$(".notification-counter").hide();
        $('.notification-container').addClass('notification-container2');
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/783h57zy/10/

thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
$('.notification-counter')
  .filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() > 0;
  }).parents('.notification-container')
  .addClass('notification-container2');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8umt8vt/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the divs using `.each()` and `$(this)`:

```
$(function () {
    $('.notification-container').each(function () {
        if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('notification-container2');
        }
    })
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/783h57zy/13/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate on the elements and then update the class.

You need to update your code to

```
$(function () {
    $(".notification-counter").each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).text()) > 0) {
        //$(".notification-counter").hide();
        $(this).parent().addClass('notification-container2');
    }
    });

});
```

Here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/783h57zy/12/

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your divs and check them separately:

[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/): loop through divs

['.parent()'](https://api.jquery.com/parent/): get the container div

$(this): use the current object

```js
$(function () {
    $('.notification-counter').each(function () {
        if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 0) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('notification-container').addClass('notification-container2');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('notification-container2').addClass('notification-container');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notification-container">
    <div class="notification-counter">200</div>
</div>
<div class="notification-container">
    <div class="notification-counter">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are many instances of the same class on the page, you need to run through each instance and make the decision based on each element.

```
$(function () {

    $('.notification-counter').each(function(){

        if( parseInt($(this).html()) === 0 ) {
            $(this).addClass('notification-container2');
        }

    });

});
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/783h57zy/14/